# What is the difference between thread safe and thread compatible?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, grpc

What is the difference between thread safe and thread compatible?

- What thread compatible mean?
- What is use cases for thread compatible?

**UPD:** 
I have found this definition in the [grpc documentation of StreamObserver](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.html).

Also, I have found the link to [Characterizing thread safety](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09263/) but its still not clear for me.

If a method requires to be in synchronize block, that means that is just threaded unsafe?

Comment: Some context on where you even found the term "thread compatible" would be great, I've never even heard of it. I imagine the distinction would be how much the user would be involved in ensuring that the API is being used in a manner that would then be considered "thread-safe"

Comment: even I never heard this word "thread compatible". Can you post the complete context of the source ?

Comment: I have updated the question with context information.

Comment: Looks like the term was coined in "Effective Java 1st edition" - see my answer below.

Comment: Here is another framework documentation that mentions this term, https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#requirements-for-writing-user-code-for-beam-transforms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Thread safe* means that an object can be used by many threads concurrently and still be correct <sup>1</sup>

*Thread hostile* means that the object does something (mutates static state, thread local storage etc.) that prevents it from being thread safe.

*Thread compatible* means not *thread safe*, but not *thread hostile* - so to satisfy thread safety, the user must perform synchronization themselves

---

1 But the definition of correctness varies a little...

[Java In Theory And In Practice](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09263/index.html) defines this according to the class's specification.

[Geoff Romer at Google](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2018/blob/master/Presentations/what_do_you_mean_threadsafe/what_do_you_mean_threadsafe__geoff_romer__cppcon_2018.pdf) and Wikipedia define this as simply lack of data races.

I usually hope this to mean no crashes, deadlocks or other surprises.

Answer (score 1):

thread safe means that the object is safe to use concurrently in multiple threads, it is implemented by java self;
although thread compatiple is not thread safe,  it still can be safe to use concurrently when you surround some synchronization code in your non-thread-safe code or have a wrapper object where it is thread safe.Namely that you shoud implement is by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the definion of `thread compatible` is due to Joshua Bloch's in *Effective Java 1st edition*. For whatever it's worth it is not present in the second edition. In the second edition we have the following taxonomy

- immutable
- unconditionally thread-safe
- conditionally thread-safe
- not thread-safe
- thread-hostile

Looks to me that `thread compatible` was renamed to `not thread-safe`.

Comment: why do you think so? It looks to me it is renamed to `conditionally thread-safe`. The documentation of Beam uses the term, "thread-compatible" just like the meaning, `conditionally thread-safe`. (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#requirements-for-writing-user-code-for-beam-transforms)